# Basic inheritance of regularity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> **Basic inheritance of regularity.** Let $G$ be a graph and $X,Y\subseteq V(G)$. If $(X,Y)$ is an $\varepsilon\eta$-regular pair,
> then $(X',Y')$ is $\varepsilon$-regular for all $X'\subseteq X$ with
> $|X'|\geq \eta|X|$ and $Y'\subseteq Y$ with $|Y'|\geq \eta |Y|$.

I struggled with this problem a bit but failed to solve it. At least I will write some of my thoughts.

Fix such a pair $(X',Y')$ and let's try to show that this pair is $\varepsilon$-regular. Consider $A\subseteq X'$ with $|A|\geq \varepsilon|X'|$ and $B\subseteq Y'$ with $|B|\geq \varepsilon|Y'|$ and our goal to show that $|d(A,B)-d(X',Y')|\leq \varepsilon.$

We see that $A\subset X, B\subset Y$ with $|A|\geq \varepsilon\eta |X|, |B|\geq \varepsilon\eta |Y|$ and since $(X,Y)$ is $\varepsilon\eta$-regular, then $|d(A,B)-d(X,Y)|\leq \varepsilon\eta$.

Then by triangle inequality we have $$|d(A,B)-d(X',Y')|\leq |d(A,B)-d(X,Y)|+|d(X,Y)-d(X',Y')|.$$

I was able to obtain some estimates for $|d(X,Y)-d(X',Y')|$ but it did not work out.

I believe that I am using wrong approach.
I spent a day trying to crack it but now I would like to see the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: You stop when you're almost at the solution. What didn't work out exactly - and why? At the very least, you should be able to finish when $\varepsilon \le \frac12$ (and I'm not 100% convinced the result holds when $\varepsilon > \frac12$).

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Hi Misha! Am I right that here $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$ are in $(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes - the definition of $\varepsilon$-regularity is silly otherwise.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, if $\varepsilon,\eta\in (0,1)$, then I can prove the statement of the problem (I will upload the proof tomorrow morning). But one thing which I cannot understand why $\varepsilon,\eta$ in that question are in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I guess we can allow other cases. If $\eta > 1$ then the statement of the problem holds trivially (there are no $X'$ and $Y'$ to check) and if $\varepsilon > 1$ then for a similar reason it is trivially true that any pair is a $\varepsilon$-regular pair.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, sorry I was wrong and I found a mistake in my solution. Anyway, let me write my thoughts: our goal is to estimate $|d(X,Y)-d(X',Y')|$. Firstly, we can write $e(X,Y)=e(X',Y')+e(X',Y-Y')+e(X-X',Y)$. Then it follows that $|d(X,Y)-d(X',Y')|=\left| e(X',Y')\left(\frac{1}{|X||Y|}-\frac{1}{|X'||Y'|}\right)+\frac{e(X',Y-Y')+e(X-X',Y)}{|X||Y|}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\eta^2}+1-2\eta$. And this estimate does not give the desired result.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, after writing my first comment the following idea came to my mind: we can assume that $\varepsilon,\eta\in (0,1)$ and each $X,Y,X',Y'\neq \varnothing$ (otherwise edge density $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ does not make sense). Since $X'\subset X,\ Y'\subset Y$ with $|X'|\geq \eta|X|,\ |Y'|\geq \eta|Y|$, then $|X'|\geq \eta\varepsilon|X|,\ |Y'|\geq \eta\varepsilon|Y|$ (here we actlually use the fact of nonemptiness) and hence $|d(X,Y)-d(X',Y')|\leq \varepsilon\eta$. and by triangle inequality: $|d(A,B)-d(X',Y')|\leq 2\varepsilon \eta$ and this is $\leq \varepsilon$ if $\eta\leq 1/2$.

Comment: That was my idea. *In applications* having this result for $\eta \le \frac12$ is always good enough; I don't know if the problem writer had some trick in mind for getting this lemma to work when $\eta > \frac12$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, agree! I also do not see any other way how to prove it for $\eta>\frac{1}{2}$. But let me ask you two general questions: 1) I have not seen any applications of Regularity Lemma and I don't know even the proof yet but I am moving towards it. Does it have any other applications except Roth's (3AP) and Szemeredi's theorem ($k$-AP)? 2) Inheritance property of regularity which I proved here. Is it used anywhere or is it just basic exercise? I am asking this question because you wrote "in applications having this result for $\eta\leq \frac{1}{2}$".

Comment: (1) It gets used all the time in extremal graph theory. There are, for example, many Ramsey problems for long paths and cycles which have been asymptotically solved using the regularity lemma. (2) Actually, I'd like to update my claim about applications: in applications getting a $2\varepsilon\eta$-regular pair is good enough (since we can always choose a smaller $\varepsilon$ to start with) but the use of the claim is not limited to $\eta<\frac12$. For example, $X'$ and $Y'$ might just be $X$ and $Y$ with a few "misbehaving" vertices deleted, in which $\eta$ might be close to $1$.

Comment: Comments are not for advertizing other questions.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Of course! I know that but I thought maybe you can help me or not. Thank you!